# Correct use of stative verbs

Tags: stative-verbs

My question is what is correct to say :

> - This concerns you.
> - This is concerning you.

Comment: Both sentences are grammatical. (They are also both ambiguous. Without further context, it's not clear if it's something of concern *to* the person or something that is *about* the person.)

Answer (score 1):

*This concerns you.* sounds correct.

There are some verbs that are not usually used in the progressive but mainly used in the present or past simple. These are called **stative verbs**. These verbs often refer to emotions, senses, and mental states. e.g.: love, see, know… The verb *concern* is a *stative verb* and is therefore not usually used in progressive.

However, a few stative verbs are sometimes used with present and past progressive forms. You use a progressive form,  when you want to emphasize that a state  is temporary. e.g.: *I'm loving it*. Some people think this usage is incorrect, and it is usually avoided in formal text.